# Module homomorphism lifts to a homomorphism of projective resolutions

Tags: proof-explanation, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

The following is Dummit and Foote's proof of the result (Chapter 17, Section 1):

[image]

What I don't understand is how the authors conclude in the second-to-last sentence that "the projectivity of $P_{n + 1}$ implies that we may lift the map $f_n d_{n + 1}\colon P_{n + 1}\to P'_n$ to ...". The map $d_{n + 1}'$ needn't be surjective, so how can projectivity of $P_{n + 1}$ ensure such a lift?

(I am aware only of the fact any homomorphism from a projective module factors through any surjective homomorphism.)

Comment: It surjects onto its image, and the image contains that of $f_n d_{n+1}$ (third-to-last sentence).

Comment: @MatthewTowers That cleared it up! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you have an exact row, $P$ is projective and $bu=0$, as in the diagram below:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
{} && P\\ 
{} @VuVV \\ 
A @>>a> B @>>b> C
\end{CD}$$

then there exists an arrow $P\longrightarrow A$ making the diagram commute. Indeed, since $bu=0$, the image of $u$ is contained in the kernel of $b$ which is the image of $a$, and hence you can replace the diagram with the usual lifting diagram defining projectives:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
{} && P\\ 
{} @VuVV \\ 
A @>>a> \mathrm{im}\ a @>>> 0
\end{CD}$$